# Using $onChanges vs $onInit in angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components

Is there a difference between using `Controller1` vs `Controller2`?

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.component('foo', {
    templateUrl: 'foo.html',
    bindings: {
        user: '<',
    },
    controller: Controller1, //Or Controller2
});

function Controller1(){
    this.$onInit = function(){
      this.user = angular.copy(this.user);
    };

    this.$onChanges = function(changes){
      if(changes.user && !changes.user.isFirstChange()){
        this.user = angular.copy(changes.user.currentValue);
      }
    };
}


function Controller2(){
    this.$onChanges = function(changes){
      if(changes.user){
        this.user = angular.copy(changes.user.currentValue);
      }
    };
}
```

Why should I bother with `$onInit` when I can just do the same this in `$onChanges` and save some rows?

Is this type of initialization better in `$onChanges` and `$onInit` better for some other kind of initialization?

Answer (score 0):

**$onInit**

Called on each controller after all the controllers on an element have been constructed and had their bindings initialized (and before the pre & post linking functions for the directives on this element). This is a good place to put initialization code for your controller.

**$onChanges**

The $onChanges lifecycle hook gets called for a few reasons. The first, is on component initialisation, it passes down that initial changes Object at runtime, so we can grab our data straight away. The second reason it gets called is only when changes occur to '<' (one-way databinding) and '@' (for evaluated DOM attribute values) that are being bound to from the parent component. Once `$onChanges` gets called, you’ll get a special changes Object back that you can hook into, which we’ll explore in the upcoming sections.

The primary practical difference is `$onInit` will be called only on the directive initialisation but `$onChanges` will be called during initialisation and when `<` and `@` variables changes.